# I have a problem with writing to my excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am getting error message when im trying to write to my excel file.

On this line: df_Percent_Change.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=x, startcol=8)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/Dropbox (Diagona)/DS/Python/Byggmarknad_index/Byggmarknad_index.py", line 125, in 
    df_Percent_Change.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=x, startcol=8)
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1766, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 652, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1742, in write_cells
    wks = self.book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 179, in add_worksheet
    return self._add_sheet(name, worksheet_class=worksheet_class)
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 666, in _add_sheet
    name = self._check_sheetname(name, isinstance(worksheet, Chartsheet))
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 717, in _check_sheetname
    if len(sheetname) > 31:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
Exception ignored in: >
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david.soderstrom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 154, in **del**
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.

```
# Calculate and save the percent change for each asset
if 'Percent_Change' not in excel_db.columns:
      print('Percent_Change does not exist in excel file.')
      print('Calculating...')


# Loop through and read each sheet
x = 0
for x in range(countSheets):
    # Read in data for the calculation
    data = pd.read_excel('databas.xlsx', sheet_name=x, index_col='Date')

    # Calculate the percent change from day to day
    Percent_Change = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()*100
    print(type(Percent_Change))
    df_Percent_Change = pd.DataFrame(Percent_Change)
    print(type(df_Percent_Change))

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('databas.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df_Percent_Change.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=x, startcol=8)

    # Save the result
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
    x += 1
```

Comment: Please add the full backtrace. That last line isn’t where the exception is happening, just where it is caught, so it doesn’t explain anything.

Comment: Hi, i have edited the post with full error message. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are using a int as the sheetname instead of a string, which is raising the exception. Try converting it to a string first.

Comment: It didnt work. It works fine with sheet_name=x on all my read_excel lines...?

Comment: seems to work with the correct as you suggested.
df_Percent_Change.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(xls.sheet_names[x]), startcol=8)
But, whats the difference between read_excel and to_excel? since it works with integer as sheet name on the read?